# Http live streaming for ipad, iphone and safari

Tags: ipad, ffmpeg

Anyone help me to find a solution to stream a video from a mac server to iPad, iPhone  and mac safari using HTTP live streaming.

Steps taken:

1. Installed and configured FFMPEG for encoding
2. installed the mediasegmenter provided by the Apple.

The ffmpeg option used is

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -acodec aac -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -s 1024×768 -vcodec libx264 -b 1200k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 1200k -maxrate 1200k -bufsize 1200k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 4:3 -r 30 -g 90 -async 2 output.mp4`

I have tried different ffmpeg options to stream the video.In some options it works in Iphone and Safari browser in mac machine, but I didn't get an option for iPad.

I want to stream an mp4 video for ipad, iPhone and mac safari. I also tried it with opensource segmenter .

Have any solution for this?

Thanks,

Riyas

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ffmpeg -i #INPUT# -acodec libfaac -ac 1 -ar 16000 -vcodec libx264 -vpre medium -vpre libx264-ipod320   -aspect 16:9 -bt 200k -crf 22 -threads 0 -y #OUTPUT#
```